# In DRF, how can I serialize the data retrieved from an ad-hot route?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the 3 models below:

```
#Appointment
class Appointment(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(
        Doctor,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='doctor_appointment')
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='patient_appointment')
    scheduled = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# Doctor
class Doctor(models.Model):
    user_id = models.TextField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

# Patients
class Patient(models.Model):
    user_id = models.TextField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

and their 3 respective serializers:

```
    # Patient Serializer
class PatientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # contract_number = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Contract.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'

    # Doctor Serializer
class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tariff = serializers.DecimalField(
        source='DoctorTariff.amount',
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'



   # Appointment Serializer
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doctor = serializers.CharField(source='Doctor.user_id')
    patient = serializers.CharField(source='Patient.user_id')
    service_provided = serializers.CharField(source='ServiceProvided.service')
    upcoming = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = '__all__'
```

For my `Appointment` model, I've specified an ad-hoc route that will show the upcoming appointment:

```
class AppointmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Appointment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppointmentSerializer

    @action(detail=False, url_path='upcoming/(?P<user_id>[^/.]+)')
    def upcoming_appointment(self, request, user_id=None):
        try:
            queryset = Appointment.objects.filter(patient__user_id=user_id).\
                select_related('patient', 'doctor').values('scheduled', doctor_first_name=F('doctor__first_name'),
                                                           doctor_last_name=F('doctor__last_name'),
                                                           specialty=F('doctor__specialty'),
                                                           doctor_address=F('doctor__address'))

            #serializer = AppointmentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            # if serializer.is_valid():

        except Appointment.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        # If I use serializer.data instead of queryset I get an error
        return Response(queryset, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This code works fine, meaning that If I hit the `upcoming` endpoint I can see the desired output.

**Question #1**: Since I can see the correct output (in a JSON format) when hitting this endpoint do I still need to use a serializer?

**Question #2**: When I'm trying to serialize this using `serializer = AppointmentSerializer(queryset, many=True)` and  `return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)` I get the error below:

*AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `doctor` on serializer `AppointmentSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Doctor'*

How can I serialize this custom query-set?

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of problems here.

Firstly, as I previously said to you, you shouldn't be using `values`. Pass the Appointment queryset directly to the serializer.

And secondly, your source names are wrong in the serializer fields. Both the fields `doctor` and `patient` are defined with a lower case, so that is the name you should use in the source attribute.

So:

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    doctor = serializers.CharField(source='doctor.user_id')
    patient = serializers.CharField(source='patient.user_id')
    ...
```

```
def upcoming_appointment(self, request, user_id=None):
    try:
        queryset = Appointment.objects.filter(patient__user_id=user_id).\
            select_related('patient', 'doctor')
        serializer = AppointmentSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer(again). But how can I get specific fields from my queryset w/o using  values()? Also, aren't the source fields referencing the Doctor and Patient classes?

Comment: Plus, trying out your solution, I get the same error as before but for 'doctor' instead of 'Doctor'. (i.e.Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'doctor'.)